# CSS: Remove drop shadow from div inside Vuetify dialog that has drop shadow

Tags: css, vuetify.js

I have a dialog where, with CSS on a div I've added a triangle. But the trick with the CSS is that part of the border is transparent. The issue I'm trying to overcome is removing the shadow from the transparent border without removing the drop shadow from the dialog itself.

adding this to the div does not work:

```
box-shadow: none;
```

Here is a pic of what I'm trying to remove:[image]

The class on the div that's creating this triangle is this:

```
.arrow-up {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 25px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 25px solid white;
}
```

And then the dialog that has the drop shadow is this:

```
<v-dialog 
  v-model="dialog" 
  max-width="350px"
  persistent
  hide-overlay
>
<div class="arrow-up mb-n1 ml-1"></div>
  <v-card>
    <v-container>
    <v-card-text>
    <v-row>
      <v-col 
        cols="12"
        align="start"
      >
        <p class="text-subtitle-1">
        Always best to start at the beginning, let's pull your products first.</p>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
    </v-card-text>
      
      <v-card-actions class="mt-n8">
        <v-btn
          color="#68007d"
          text
          @click="closeEverything"
        >
          CLOSE
        </v-btn>
      </v-card-actions>
    </v-container>
  </v-card>
</v-dialog>
```

The `v-dialog` itself has this class creating the shadow

```
.v-dialog {
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin: 24px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    pointer-events: auto;
    transition: .3s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);
    width: 100%;
    z-index: inherit;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0 11px 15px -7px rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0 24px 38px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.14), 0 9px 46px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.12);
}
```

Comment: Please make an example where you can see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you need to remove the box shadow from the dialog and add it to the card. To see the box shadow on the card though you need to remove the overflow rule on the dialog.

You will probably want to tweak the box shadow to what suits.

**CSS:**

```
.v-dialog {
  box-shadow: none;
  overflow: visible;
}

.arrow-up {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 25px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 25px solid white;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.v-sheet.v-card:not(.v-sheet--outlined) {
  box-shadow: 0px -16px 50px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.14), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12);
}
```

**Example:** [Codepen](https://codepen.io/alexpetergill/pen/NWOVZVq/6ce3c3e6c35755432db0815dc3188634)